# Cannot load modern controls UI. Unable to play YouTube videos in full screen

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I recently have updated YouTube Android Player API to 1.2.2 (the latest version), but it keeps telling me

```
16445-16445/com.* W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI﹕ Cannot load modern controls UI. Upgrade to the latest version of the Android YouTube API.
```

, when I try to put a video on the fullscreen mode. In addition, the video stops playing and it appears, that it can’t be played anymore (it stucks). What’s even worse, when you press back, it does not allow you to play the video in normal mode, so, basically, you have to reload the activity. I’m using `YoutubePlayerSupportFragment`. I guess, that the general YouTube app update might have ruined it. I have noticed, that the full screen mode worked smoothly before.

How to overcome with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37181075/4733198 This is my question and answer.
I hope it will be help.

Answer (score 1):

When you extend `AppCompatActivity`, It causes 2 following problems:

1. It causes error `UNAUTHORIZED_OVERLAY` when playing in fullscreen. Because the statusbar is on the top of YoutubePlayer.
   Solution: set `FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT` to hide the status bar manually.
2. `YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI﹕ Cannot load modern controls UI. Upgrade to the latest version of the Android YouTube API.`
   The UI of YoutubePlayer looks so bad. It just happens when extending `AppCombatActivity`. Updating the latest youtube api doesn't work.
   If you find the solution of the 2nd problem, please let me know.

Comment: For the second problem. use getLayoutInflater().setFactory(this);
 in onCreate function but before super.onCreate . I have been testing that there is no problem so far. However, it may cause some problems for some other apps and devices.