# Upgrade to the latest version of the Android YouTube API

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

The Android App does using `YoutubeBaseActivity` does not play video.

The Log is same with the title.

**"Cannot load modern controls UI. Upgrade to the latest version of the Android YouTube API."**

I think it is because I have updated the Youtube App.
Videos have played with no problem after I deleted the Youtube App Updates.

But this is not the solution. Many people installed this app from Google Play Market and are using it.
Is it a problem of Google not supporting newest Android Youtube API?
Should I wait for API updates?

Comment: Check this SO question [32784730](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784730/unable-to-play-some-youtube-videos-using-youtube-android-player-api) and [33363456](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363456/cannot-load-modern-controls-ui-upgrade-to-the-latest-version-of-the-android-you) if it can help you;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use gradle for your dependencies. This is the last version:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev171-1.20.0'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev171-1.20.0'
is only for regular Java project, not for Android.
I need Youtube Player Api.

Comment: And it seems like they don't provide Player Api for gradle yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself!

**The answer is that
"Delete the Youtube video and upload it again."**

I tried to install the Youtube API sample app.
And found that some videos are well done but some are not.
I assume that the process of uploading videos has changed (just my opinion).

Thank you for all your attension and answers.

Comment: this is not a solution if you need to play the other's videos

Comment: Hmm.. my question is about the Android Youtube API. What are you meaning [the other's vedeos] ?